# How can I make an array from a sql query result?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, arrays, model-view-controller

> I wan't to have an array result [1000, 0, 0, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3210, 0] from 1 array and sql MySqlDataReader sdr.Read() result.

**here are the arrays**

```
ArrayList array1 = new ArrayList()[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
ArrayList arrayresult = new ArrayList();
while (sdr.Read())
{
      transactions.Add(new transaction_details
            {
                  ID = Int32.Parse(sdr["ID"].ToString()),
                  Transdate = DateTime.Parse(sdr["Transdate"].ToString()),
                  Debit = Decimal.Parse(sdr["Debit"].ToString()),
                  TransactionName = sdr["TransactionName"].ToString()
            });
}
//arrayresult.add() - what do I do with this ?
```

> If ID in sdr["ID"].ToString() is in array1, then the result would be [ 1, 4, 9]. array1 has 10 index so for final result I want it to be [ 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]. If ID does not exist, 0 will be inserted.
>
> I need arrayresult to have this result.

```
var debit = [1000, 0, 0 ,500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3210, 0];
var ID = [ 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0];
var date= [ "2020-01-01", 0, 0, "2020-01-02", 0, 0, 0, 0, "2020-01-03", 0];
```

> 

Comment: Also, there is no reason to ever use `ArrayList` today. It was obsoleted in 2005 when `List<T>` was introduced.

Comment: This is **not** how you're supposed to use a `DbDataReader`:  `Decimal.Parse(sdr["Debit"].ToString())`

Comment: @Dai how can I have same result using List<T> ?

Comment: @Dai what does this mean ? "This is not how you're supposed to use a DbDataReader"

Comment: To store heterogeneously-typed values, use `List<Object>` instead of `ArrayList`. However, why are you using zeroes to represent `null`/absent entries? Why not use `List<Int32?>` or `List<DateTime?>` instead of using integer zeroes?

Comment: @Dai what do I do with 0's when while will only loop 3 times because there are only 3 data to be read not 10.

Comment: You're using `DbDataReader` incorrectly. Don't do `ID = Int32.Parse(sdr["ID"].ToString()),` - instead use `sdr.GetInt32("ID")`.

Comment: @Dai oohh. Tnx. Let me try.

Comment: "while will only loop 3 time" - What loop?

Comment: @Dai what's the difference between the 2 ?

Comment: @Dai this loop while (sdr.Read())

Answer (score 0):

Short linq pseudo code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<int> inp = new List<int>(){1,4,9};

            List<int> array1 = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
            var array1Index = array1.Select((i, index) => new { Index=index, i=i }).ToList();

            List<int> arrayresult = new List<int>();

            var query = from p in array1Index
                select inp.Contains(p.i)==true?p.i:0;

            arrayresult = query.ToList();
            arrayresult.ForEach(x=>{
                Console.Write(x+" ");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cant use linq because my database name is dynamic. It is base on model return value. example database_a, database_b, database_c ... database_z. if value is b. the database will be database_b.

Comment: @DamHarvey Linq-to-Objects has absolutely nothing to do with Databases. You're thinking of Entity Framework which uses Linq-to-Entities, but even then, you **can** still use Linq with database object names determined at runtime.

Comment: @Dai do you have the link for an example ?

Comment: @DamHarvey An example to what? Entity Framework is a framework which requires modelling and setting configuration and comes with a steep learning-curve - it's not something anyone can gives an "example" of.

Comment: @Dai I mean, an example of dynamic database query that will use linq instead of MySqlConnection and MySqlDataReader.

Comment: @DamHarvey Entity Framework still uses connection-strings, so you change the target database name in there. As for `MySqlDataReader`, that's still used by EF, but used internally so you don't need to interact with it directly.

Comment: @Dai connectionstring is in web.config and I can't use variable in web.config.

Comment: @DamHarvey Your application code can read the connection-string in the web.config file, make its own changes to it (such as changing the database name), and then pass it to the `DbContext` constructor. You don't have to use the defaults for everything. Please do more research before asking questions with answers you can find within minutes of googling.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="database_a" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=0.0.0.0;database=databasename;Integrated Security=True;uid=username;password=password;port=8080" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @Dai how can I do from a - z in that ?

Comment: @DamHarvey With `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: @Dai not in web.config ?

Comment: @DamHarvey I think you're getting ahead of yourself if you can't see how to use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` with data loaded from `web.config` using `ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: @Dai I dont know how to use MySqlConnectionStringBuilder yet.

Comment: @Dam Harvey instead using `DataReader` use `DataSet`, retrieve all your resultset by one query and convert to `List<int>`

Comment: @NitinSawant ok2x. tnx